# Conda Environment Google Colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda, google-colaboratory

I have a Conda environment with very specific package versions and an older version of Python. My local system is a bit too slow for my machine learning code, and I'm looking to use this environment on Colab or Paperspace Gradient.

How do I go about running my Conda environment on one of these platforms?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [MiniConda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) for your case. The setup into Colab is as follows:

```py
!wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

```py
!chmod +x Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

```py
!./Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
```

```py
!conda --version # conda 4.10.3
```

The last command should print `conda 4.10.3` for current version. After that update to newest version:

```
!conda update --channel defaults --all --yes
```

Answer (score 0):

One cannot simply use any arbitrary environment. You have to match the Python version in the environment to the one Colab runs (currently v3.7), then include environment's `lib/python3.7/site-packages` in the module search path, with something like

```python
import sys

sys.path.append('/path/to/envs/lib/python3.7/site-packages/')
```